# Is "nowadays" the same as "today"?

Tags: etymology, differences, word-usage, register

When helping an Italian speaker with her written homework, a cover letter,  I told her to change the expression *nowadays* to that of *today*. Her original sentence was the following:

> I would be delighted to work for your company, as it is one of the most important software companies nowadays.

She asked why it was better to change that expression. I said it didn't sound "right". She looked at me quizzically, so I mumbled something about it being a question of register and collocation but frankly, I'm not sure.

I had better add that she wants to sit the Cambridge English exam Advanced, [CAE](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams-and-qualifications/advanced/), so I was wondering whether an examiner would look unfavourably on the expression.

Moreover, I would like to know if *nowadays* is considered a compound word? Until today,  I thought it was made up of three words; *now, a* and *days*. But [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nowadays) tells me that it was originally two words: ***now*** and ***adayes***. *Adayes* used to mean "during the day", which I think is lovely and I wish it would make a comeback. 
In any case, did the hyphenated form, *now-adayes* ever existed?

I know there is a similar question on ELU to this one, ["Nowadays" vs "today"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46771/nowadays-vs-today) but it hasn't really answered any of my questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you were on the right track when you mentioned it might be a question of register: to me, *nowadays* is old-fashioned in a sort of folksy way, rather than a "we're not that exact anymore" archaic way that would actually make a word *more* formal. But that's just my gut feeling, no support whatsoever.

> **[nowadays](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nowadays?s=t)**   (adverb)
>   at the present day; in these times: *Few people do their laundry by hand nowadays.*

> **[today](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/today?s=t)**   (adverb)
>   1. on this present day: *I will do it today.*
>   2. at the present time; in these days: *Today you seldom see horses.*

So the second meaning of "today" is more-or-less identical to "nowadays", but that's not the meaning you want when you're trying to say you *approve* of something. **Today** is the bright, shiny, new day of opportunity; **nowadays** is the faded shadow of yesteryear. As Prof. Lawler said, "*nowadays* is often used to disparage present conditions in contrast to the past."

Oops, forgot to address the compound word part of your question. I've certainly never considered "nowadays" to be a compound of anything, because if you subtract the obvious "now" part, you're left with "adays", which doesn't look like a word. Most compounds have two parts, so it would be a bit of stretch to break it down as *now + a + days*, though I suppose that's possible, and I'm sure you're not the only person who has ever done so.

Comment: I'd upvote your answer now but I've reached my quota!

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that seems to be going around these days. Something about hats?

Comment: Unfortunately tHats seems very likely.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: THWACK!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your recommendation.  While it's not technically an error, in my judgement "Nowadays" will probably be perceived as a colloquialism, and therefore sounds less erudite.

Comment: Well, this student of mine would like to sit the English exam, the CAE. I was thinking would an examiner mark her down? Maybe I should include this comment in my question. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: It's not an error at all, but _today_ is a bright shiny marketing term, while _nowadays_ is often used to disparage present conditions in contrast to the past. In this kind of letter, one wants to avoid any hint of disparagement.

Comment: Could you post that as an answer, please? It makes a lot of sense!