# Was "nowadays" ever spelled with hyphens?

Tags: etymology, orthography, hyphenation

etymonline doesn't note that [nowadays](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=nowadays&allowed_in_frame=0) ever had a spelling with hyphen but I found a few random sites claiming that it once was hyphenated. Was it ever spelled as "now-a-days"?

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142760/is-nowadays-the-same-as-today/142773#142773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Ngram has an answer for you [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nowadays,%20now-a-days&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,nowadays;,c0;.t1;,now%20-%20a%20-%20days;,c0)  The hyphen-free form is significantly more common than the hyphenated form.  Google Ngram plots the frequency of words and phrases as a function of time.  As you can see from the graph, *nowadays* is significantly more common than *now-a-days"*.

Comment: Do you mind summarizing the answer in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

The OED has citations showing the adverb spelt as *nou adaies, now a days, now adaies* and *now a days*. There are just two showing the hyphenated *now-a-days*, and one showing the adjective as *now-adaies*.

Comment: Does that mean no, it wasn't spelled with hyphens?

Comment: Well, clearly it was, at least twice.

Answer (score 1):

I have certainly seen it spelt *now-a-days*, but this spelling is not common.  This is not so much a matter of etymology as it is one of convention.

But is the phrase itself *best* spelt with hyphens?  Let us examine it.

If we take the basic phrase *nowadays* and separate it, we get three parts: *now*, *a*, and *days*.

The adverb *now* requires little explanation, as we have seen that it was merely appended to the earlier word *adayes*.

Though I cannot say with absolute certainty, based on similar adverbs and prepositions (which have more in common than one may think), we can assume that the *a-* from *adayes* is the same as that in *aboard*, *atop*, *around*, and so on.  This *a-* usually represents a reduced form of *on* (*climb aboard the ship* is shortened from *climb on board of the ship* and so on).  Convention does not use a hyphen in this construction; with this observation, we can conclude that no hyphen is required between *a-* and *days*.

For some further prodding, we can look closely at the final element *days*.  This, when we look at its Middle English form *dayes*, is evidently from Old English *dæges*, the genitive of *dæg* 'day'.  Thus the word, in itself, means 'of day'.  In Old English, *dæges* was often used to mean 'by day'; this usage continues to the present, as we will still say 'I work days' to mean 'I work by day'.

However, the last two elements as a whole form *adays*, which may be an alteration of Old English *on dæge* 'today'.  The word *today*, which in the past was hyphenated as *to-day*, was ultimately an alteration of *on dæge*, a dative construction.  Prepositions can often take multiple cases; it would not be surprising that *on* should transfer from dative *on dæge* to genitive *on dæges*.  From this we should get *adayes*, but, as we've seen in similar words, there is no reason to hyphenate it as *to-day* and *to-night* once were.

In conclusion, there is no obvious reason to hyphenate the phrase.  If anything, the most logical way of spelling it is *now adays*, but, considering that the second part *adays* is no longer used, this is inadvisable at best.  Yes, it is occasionally hyphenated; no, it was never customary to do so, as we can see from the etymology: *on dæges* simply compressed into *adayes* before hyphens came into common use, and no one saw fit to reverse the process.