# Synonyms for Nowadays

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I am writing a technical research paper as a part of a large group and a lot of the authors are constantly using the word (phrase?) *nowadays* in their sections. Examples being:

> Nowadays a greater significance with the advent of online transactions
>
> The collection and processing of data locally inside the web browser
> is a common process nowadays for analyzing the user information.
>
> Encryption is widely used nowadays to have more control over the
> information access

What would be some apt, prudent replacement of the same that doesn't sound repetitive and feels more, say, professional?

Thanks!

Comment: *Today*, perhaps?

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus? We generally suggest that you do some research before asking. Please check out [the help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: related: [Is “nowadays” the same as “today”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142760/is-nowadays-the-same-as-today)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, "These Days" could fit in this situation, or just simply "Now," would fit in this example you listed.