# Usage of "nowadays"

Tags: adverbs

Should I use "nowadays" at the end or at the beginning of a sentence?
For instance: We, as advertising experts, understand what young women look for nowadays.

Comment: Depending on the context, both are possible.

Comment: Register-wise, it's chatty/slightly antiquated. You may favour this, but placing it anywhere close to 'advertising experts' seems incongruous. ... _the young woman of today_ ...?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46771/nowadays-vs-today

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Chatty? Antiquated? I would not describe it as either. It's not the most formal of words, but I wouldn't bat an eyelash to see it in an official document or something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means different things in different places:

> 1. **Nowadays** we understand what young women look for. ...

We didn't understand in the past what young women look for, but now we do.

> 2. We understand what young women look for **nowadays**. ...

We understand what young women look for now, which is not what they looked for in the past.

Comment: True, although a simple comma ("We understand what young women look for, nowadays") takes us back to the meaning of sentence one - although you might be well advised to just rephrase it as sentence one

Comment: @Au101 I'm not sure it's that simple. Seems to me the comma just marks *nowadays* as a supplement, but doesn't assure that it's attached to the matrix clause. You could however accomplish that by moving *nowadays*, comma-bracketed, after *understand*.

Comment: So first case, it's used for understand. Second case, it's used for look for?

Answer (score 3):

The following extract from *M-W Learners Dictionary* explains its usage:

***[Nowadays](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/about-nowadays):*** (take care to spell nowadays correctly: not ‘nowdays’.)

> ***Nowadays is an adverb that means “these days” or “during this time.”*** It suggests a period of months or years, rather than days, and it is normally used to talk about things that happen again and again, such as habits or routines.
>
> Here are some example sentences with nowadays:
>
> - *Nowadays, many people need two jobs in order to make ends meet.*
> - *People don't wear hats much nowadays.*
>
> ***Nowadays is typically used with the simple present tense***, as in the examples above, ***but it is fine to use it with a continuous tense,*** as long as you are referring to a something that repeats over a period of time. Here are two examples of nowadays with the present continuous:
>
> - *Nowadays, I'm relying on my husband to do the food shopping.*
> - *A lot of women can’t afford to stay home with the kids nowadays.*
>
> However, your sentence about the man opening a massage studio, sounds awkward with nowadays, because it sounds like the man is starting a business, and he is probably not opening the same business again and again.
>
> Here are some alternatives that would sound better to most English speakers:
>
> - *He is opening a massage studio soon.*
> - *He is opening a massage studio next week.*
> - *He is preparing to open a massage studio.*
> - *He plans to open a massage studio next month.*